# Can I use a USB 2.0 female to RJ45 cable to print docs sent to my router connected printer?

Tags: usb, printer, laser-printer, rj-45

Can I use a USB 2.0 female to RJ45 cable to print docs sent to my router connected printer (USB only). A device like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014UU7ZFI)? Why do people use a print  server if it can work like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you linked to is just a mechanical adapter, that allows CAT5/6/7 cable to be easily used **as a transport medium** for USB, but it will not convert the protocol spoken over this link from USB-Printer interface class to Ethernet.

To be blunt: If you plug the RJ45 End into a Switch (or your Router) and the USB end into your Printer, then neither will the Switch (or Router) see a connection, nor the printer.

To print via TCP/IP over Ethernet takes many more steps, some obvious (how would your printer get an IP address), some less visible (different signalling on the analog layer). This is, what an USB print server does.

Comment: And a USB print server may not work with low-cost GDI printers, unless it specifically supports your printer.